# Estimate element of sequence

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

$T(n) = 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n$

(I already figured out this is always equal to $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$, can I use this?)

$P(n) = \frac{T(2)}{T(2) - 1} . \frac{T(3)}{T(3)-1} . \frac{T(4)}{T(4)-1} . ... . \frac{T(n)}{T(n) - 1}$

How can I estimate $P(1991)$?

Comment: Hint:  $T(n)-1=\frac {(n+2)(n-1)}2$.

Comment: That changes the definition of $P(n) = \frac{2(2+1)}{(2+2)(2-1)} . \frac{3(3+1)}{(3+2)(3-1)} . ... . \frac{n(n+1)}{n+2)(n-1)}$. And now? Am I missing an obvious pattern?

Answer (score 0):

Using that $\,T(n)-1=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}-1 = \frac{n^2+n-2}{2}=\frac{(n+2)(n-1)}{2}\,$:

$$
T(n)-1 = \frac{(n+2)(n+1)}{2} \cdot \frac{2}{(n+1)n} \cdot \frac{n(n-1)}{2}=\frac{T(n+1) T(n-1)}{T(n)}
$$

Then:

$$\require{cancel}
\begin{align}
& \quad\;\; \frac{T(2)}{T(2) - 1} \cdot \frac{T(3)}{T(3)-1} \cdot \frac{T(4)}{T(4)-1} \cdots \frac{T(n)}{T(n) - 1} \\[5px]
&= \frac{T^{\color{red}{\cancel{2}}}(2)}{T(1)\color{blue}{\bcancel{T(3)}}} \cdot \frac{\color{blue}{\bcancel{T^2(3)}}}{\color{red}{\cancel{T(2)}}\xcancel{T(4)}} \cdot \frac{\xcancel{T^2(4)}}{\color{blue}{\bcancel{T(3)}}\cancel{T(5)}} \cdots \\[5px]
& \quad\quad\quad\quad \cdots \frac{\cancel{T^2(n-2)}}{\bcancel{T(n-3)}\xcancel{T(n-1)}} \cdot \frac{\xcancel{T^2(n-1)}}{\cancel{T(n-2)}\color{red}{\cancel{T(n)}}} \cdot \frac{T^{\color{red}{\cancel{2}}}(n)}{\xcancel{T(n-1)}T(n+1)} \\[5px]
&= \frac{T(2)\,T(n)}{T(1) T(n+1)} = \frac{3 \cdot \frac{n\cancel{(n+1)}}{\bcancel{2}}}{1 \cdot \frac{\cancel{(n+1)}(n+2)}{\bcancel{2}}} = \frac{3n}{n+2}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{\color{blue}{2} \times 3}{ 1 \times \color{red}{4}} \times  \frac{\color{orange}{3} \times \color{red}{4}}{ \color{blue}{2} \times \color{pink}{5}} 
\times \frac{\color{blue}{4} \times \color{pink}{5}}{ \color{orange}{3} \times \color{red}{6}} \times\cdots \\ \times
\frac{\color{orange}{(n-1)} \times \color{red}{n}}{ \color{blue}{(n-2)} \times \color{pink}{(n+1)}} \times
\frac{\color{blue}{n} \times \color{pink}{(n+1)}}{ \color{orange}{(n-1)} \times \color{red}{(n+2)}} \times 
\frac{\color{orange}{(n+1)} \times \color{red}{(n+2)}}{ \color{blue}{n} \times \color{pink}{(n+3)}} \times \\
\cdots \times
\frac{\color{blue}{1990} \times \color{pink}{1991}}{ \color{orange}{1989} \times \color{red}{1992}}
 \times \frac{1991 \times \color{red}{1992}}{  \color{blue}{1990} \times  1993}
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 0):

$\displaystyle P(n)=\frac{(n)\color{green}{(n+1)}}{\color{blue}{(n-1)}(n+2)}\ \frac{\color{blue}{(n-1)}\color{green}{(n)}}{\color{blue}{(n-2)}\color{green}{(n+1)}}\ \frac{\color{blue}{(n-2)}\color{green}{(n-1)}}{\color{blue}{(n-3)}\color{green}{(n)}}\ \frac{\color{blue}{(n-3)}\color{green}{(n-2)}}{\color{blue}{(n-4)}\color{green}{(n-1)}}\cdots\frac{\color{blue}{3}.\color{green}{4}}{\color{blue}{2}.\color{green}{5}}\ \frac{\color{blue}{2}.3}{1.\color{green}{4}}$

Green and blue terms cancel each other, so you are left with $\displaystyle P(n)=\frac{3n}{n+2}$

Now if we set $P(n)=\frac{T(n)}{T(n)-1}P(n-1)$ with $P(1)=1$.

Let's prove the resulting formula by induction :

$\displaystyle P(1)=\frac{3}{1+2}=\frac 33=1\quad$ ok.

$\displaystyle P(n+1)=\frac{T(n+1)}{T(n+1)-1}P(n)=\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{(n+3)n}\times\frac{3n}{n+2}=\frac{3(n+1)}{(n+3)}=\frac{3(n+1)}{(n+1)+2}$

Which allows to conclude positively.